# git daemon doesn't allow write access

Tags: git, daemon

Here i am using a local area network to access git repository between the systems.

**System 1:**

Here I created a git bare-repository and make it as a daemon. I am running the command:

`Command=git daemon --verbose --export-all --enable=upload-pack --enable=receive-pack --base-path=d:/`

**System 2:**
Here i add the remote-repository and try to preform push and pull.I am trying the commands:

`Commands:$ git remote add origin git://192.168.1.8/server.git
$ git push -u origin master`

**It shows:** 
`error:counting objects:13, done.
delta compression using up to 4 threads.
compressing objects:100%(7/7), done.
writing objects:100% (9/9)`

but the cursor doesn't come to the next line, it stays at that line and blinks. If we press `ctrl+c` then it come to the next line and at the System 1's daemon server it prints:

`fatal:write error:Invalid argument`

Can you please help me?

Comment: What OS the remote and client computers use?

Comment: Have you tried running `GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1 git push -u origin master`?  It might give you some useful debugging information.